# What are the possible values of $a$ such that $f(x) = (x + a)(x + 1991) + 1$ has two integer roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the possible values of $a$ such that $f(x) = (x + a)(x + 1991) + 1$ has two integer roots?

$(x + a)(x + 1991) + 1 = x^2 + (1991 + a)x + (1991a + 1)$

This is of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$. Applying the quadratic formula $\left(\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right)$, we get, that the rooots must equal:

$\frac{-(1991 + a) \pm \sqrt{(1991 + a)^2 - 4(1991a + 1)}}{2} = \frac{-(1991 + a) \pm \sqrt{1991^2 + a^2 + 2\times1991a - 4\times1991a -4}}{2} = \frac{-(1991 + a) \pm \sqrt{(1991 - a)^2 - 2^2}}{2} = \frac{-(1991 + a) \pm \sqrt{(1991 - a - 2)(1991-a+2)}}{2}$

For the formula to yield an integer, the discriminant must be a perfect square or $0$. Clearly, the discriminant will be zero if $a = 1993$ or $a = 1989$. The only thing that remains to be shown is that these are indeed the only possible solutions.

I couldn't think of any way to do so. Are there any alternate solutions, perhaps some that involve more number theory and less algebra?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(1991-a)^2-2^2=b^2$, say, then $(1991-a)^2-b^2=4$, and you have two squares that differ by $4$. Of course $2^2$ and $0^2$ work, as do $(-2)^2$ and $0^2$; these are the solutions that you already have. And they’re the only ones: if $x$ and $y$ are integers, and $x^2-y^2=4$, then $(x-y)(x+y)=4$. The factors $x-y$ and $x+y$ have the same parity, so they must both be even, and therefore either both are $2$, or both are $-2$. In either case one of $x$ and $y$ is $0$ and the other is $2$, giving you the solutions that you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, $m^2-4$ cannot be a square for $m>2$. Hint: $m^2 - (m-1)^2 = 2m-1$.

Answer (score 1):

(x + a)(x + 1991) + 1 = 0

(x + a)(x + 1991) = -1

if x is integer, then, there are two possible pairs.

I)  x+a= 1 and x+1991 = -1

II) x+a = -1, x+1991 = 1.

if we eleminate x in both system euqations,  we'll get a = 1989 and a= 1993.